# C# Многопоточность

Tags: c#, циклы, многопоточность

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Class1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static int Threads = 2;
        private static string FileToRead = "File.txt";
        private static string Target = "admin";

        private static string[] ReadFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(FileToRead);

        private static void StartThreads()
        {
            System.Threading.Thread newThread;
            newThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Scanner));
            newThread.Start();
        }

        public static void Scanner()
        {
            foreach (string Line in ReadFile)
            {
                if (Line == Target)
                {
                    Console.Write("" + Line + " == " + Target + "\r\n");
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                }
                else if (Line != Target)
                {
                    Console.Write("" + Line + " != " + Target + "\r\n");
                }
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Threads; i++)
            {
                    StartThreads();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Принцип действия код выше.

Заходит строитель на стройку и видит кучу кирпичей берет **один** кирпич и несет его **нормально** на склад, пока возвращался подумал а почему бы не взять **2 кирпича двумя руками в каждую по одному** подошел к куче и взял 2 кирпича, задумался и сходил 2 раза на склад с кирпичами в руках, взял 4 кирпича 2 в каждую ногу 2 в каждую руку понес и опять задумался и **сходит 4 раза на склад**, как сделать чтобы строитель брал например по 2 кирпича в каждую руку и **нормально относил на склад, затем возвращался еще за 2**.

код ищет строку в файле сверяет её с переменной "Target" и выводит на экран.

проблема с потоками если задать потоков 1 все будет нормально, если 2 то код будет обрабатывать **одну и туже строку 2 раза** если 3 то тоже ... и так далее ...

как решить проблему?)

сколько раз уже задавал вопрос где только не задавал никто толком не ответил если и ответил то не помогло.

Comment: Быть может вам не отвечают потому, что вам это нафиг не нужно? Чего только стоит пример вашего кода и описание на кирпичах :D

Answer (score 3):

У Вас проблема в том, что каждый поток заново перебирает весь набор строк. Нужно чтобы перебор работал независимо в каждом потоке. Для этого проще всего использоваться перечислитель массива `ReadFile`. Т.е. до старте потоков делаете `var iterator = ReadFile.GetEnumerator()` и передаете его в качестве параметра в функцию `Scanner` (или, чтобы сохранить стиль, объявляете глобально). Внутри функции `Scanner` вместо `foreach` последовательно выбираете элементы из итератора. Итератор является совместно используемым ресурсом, поэтому обращение к его методам надо защитить с помощью оператора lock:

```
string nextString;

while (true) {

    lock (iterator)
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
            break; //если строки кончились - выходим из цикла
        nextString = iterator.Current;
    }
    doSomethingWith(nextString);
}
```

Comment: чет я не улавливаю разницы с предыдущим ответом.. поясните разницу, пожалуйста - хочется разобраться

Comment: По сути - никакой. Меньше кода, больше слов. Учитывая заданный вопрос, мне показалось, что приведенного пояснения будет недостаточно.

Answer (score 2):

лочить надо просто. почитайте про lock(){}

и надо не форыч использовать, а енумератор и его лочить и при его помощить коллекцию в потоках перебирать.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread[] threads = new Thread[Environment.ProcessorCount];

            for (int i = 0; i < threads.Length; i++)
            {
                threads[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(startThread));
                threads[i].Start();
            }

        }

        private static string[] bla = new string[] { "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",     "", "", "", "" };
        private static IEnumerator tmp = bla.GetEnumerator();

        private static  void startThread()
        {
            bool exit;
            do{
                string workstr;
                lock (tmp)
                {
                    if (tmp.MoveNext())
                        workstr = tmp.Current as string;
                    else
                        exit = true;
                }
                // обработка строки
            }while (!exit);
        }
    }
}
```

примерно так, дальше допилите как надо по этому примеру. надеюсь, помог.. не проверял только - корпаратив был, не до этого :)